# Why does using GDPPC as a dependent variable dramatically change results from the GDP run?

Tags: regression, least-squares, macroeconomics

I'm testing the following hypothesis using OLS: Renewable energy has a positive impact on GDP. I converted all the variables into log.

In the 1st run I used GDP as the dependent variable and in the 2nd I used GDPPC.

[image: Model summary for comparison]

Why are the results so different? I could understand some change but this is a pretty big discrepancy. I"ve looked at a bunch of papers that do the same thing (albiet with different methods, only one using OLS) and the difference in their R-sq values are usually really small. 
I've checked to make sure the data and settings are consistent. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: GDPPC  means GDP per capita? Are your predictors per capita or total?

Comment: What is GDPPC? Have you tried plotting GDP against (possibly scaled) GDPPC to see how different they are? You could also calculate the correlation between GDP and GDPPC. If it is high, you could expect similar results in terms of $R^2$ when substituting one with the other as the dependent variable in a regression, and you would look for a mistake if the results are very different.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala yes it means GDP per capita. The predictors are total. I tried converting the predictors into per capita but it "junked" the results and collinearated (if I can use it that way) all the predictors.

Comment: @RichardHardy It seems the problem is something to do with SPSS. I ran both models in StatPlus and the GDPPC run came out fine. Having trouble making sense of the results though. The R2 is fine but the predictor's coefficients change pretty dramatically. https://postimg.org/image/yh2h75sht/ Any clue?

Comment: If you really get that different results from fitting the same model with the same data and the same method with different software, you very likely have made some mistake in one of them (so this is a software usage / programming error). Software usage questions would however be off-topic here, unless there is a possibility that the mistake arises from some misunderstanding of the methods.

Comment: But if you are convinced that the StatPlus results are correct, you should edit the question to ask about them. Though I don't understand why you are surprised that the coefficients change dramatically when the output variable changes dramatically.

Comment: You're quite right. Followed the steps on a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElkCTFkAGXY) on multivariate OLS and all seems well.